# Color Duplicates within that week

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, duplicates, conditional-formatting, countif

How do I automatically color duplicates in a column "within that week" while I am filling records in the sheet.

For Eg: All new records within the week are colored Green and duplicates within that week is colored Orange.

[image: Week wise Duplicates]

I have been trying Format > Conditional Formatting however I am not sure what to enter in the Custom Formula to limit the search and highlight week wise.

Any help is appreciated. Here's a sample sheet and expected results

[Week wise Duplicates](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W5TzBTL_Y2hhXJvmaiIa7_UmMG8bjC1GHyc6B91mxZ8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have added a link in the question.

Comment: Are you open to having helper columns for this? Otherwise, would you be open to using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if Monday is the 1st day of the week and Col1 & Col2 are treated together:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(COUNTIFS(
 IF(B2:C="",, WEEKNUM(VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A), IF(A2:A<>"", 
 {ROW(A2:A), A2:A}), 2, 1), 2)&" "&B2:C), 
 IF(B2:C="",, WEEKNUM(VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A), IF(A2:A<>"", 
 {ROW(A2:A), A2:A}), 2, 1), 2)&" "&B2:C), 
 SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A), 2), "<="&SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A), 2))>1, 1, ))
```

[image]

---

and cf would be:

[image]

---

### update

if Monday is the 1st day of the week and Col1 & Col2 are **NOT** treated together:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF({COUNTIFS(
 IF(B2:B="",, WEEKNUM(VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A), IF(A2:A<>"", 
 {ROW(A2:A), A2:A}), 2, 1), 2)&" "&B2:B), 
 IF(B2:B="",, WEEKNUM(VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A), IF(A2:A<>"", 
 {ROW(A2:A), A2:A}), 2, 1), 2)&" "&B2:B), 
 ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))>1, COUNTIFS(
 IF(C2:C="",, WEEKNUM(VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A), IF(A2:A<>"", 
 {ROW(A2:A), A2:A}), 2, 1), 2)&" "&C2:C), 
 IF(C2:C="",, WEEKNUM(VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A), IF(A2:A<>"", 
 {ROW(A2:A), A2:A}), 2, 1), 2)&" "&C2:C), 
 ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))>1}, 1, ))
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your formula. Monday is the 1st day but Col1 and Col2 are separate and not treated together. How do I change this formula to accommodate this.

Comment: @CuriousDev answer updated

Comment: Many thanks for your efforts.